# Jasper Reports: using sub-request in $X{} clause

Tags: oracle, jasper-reports

I currently have a set of parameters, one of them being a collection of some id's called  `ou_ids[]` , and in my report query it is used in $X{} clause:

`AND $X{IN, ou_id, ou_id[]}`

The trick is, now i have to compare my `ou_id` to a different set of id's which can be obtained by the following query

`SELECT DISTINCT ous.id FROM ous WHERE "OUS"."TYPE" IN ('OU::Center', 'OU::Sector') START WITH id IN (10204, 10350) CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id`

, where `(10204, 10350)` is an example set of id's, which is to be replaced by `ou_ids[]`

So basically, i have to gather a bigger set of id's by somehow processing a set i get from a parameter.

So, the **question is**: what is the best way to incorporate the new query to my report query?

Comment: Why not to create query with Join?

Comment: please be more specific - what should i join to what?

Comment: You need to show us table structure for us to understand "best way to incorporate", normal an inner join would do it.

Comment: The repot query gathers data from table named ```routes_mview``` , which has a column ```ou_id``` . My previous report query just compared that column to a collection of id's provided by report parameter. What i need now is to inject there a subquery which would gather a set of id's from table ```ous``` by doing some magic (as shown above) and compare column ```ou_id``` from ```routes_mview``` to that